# How to retrieve a user (with a specific user role) from a known group in keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I need to retrieve a specific user with a certain user role from a Keycloak user group (id is known). Presently I am doing it as below.

```
//get all users
keycloak.realm("myRealm").groups().group(groupId).members(0, 1000);
//query the list of users to identify the specific user
```

which takes some considerable amount of time (nearly 2 minutes) when the groups and the number of users increase. 
Is there a particular way to get a single user or a single group without querying all groups and users in a keycloak server.

I am using keycloak 2.3.0 Final keycloak server with a springboot application.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

With `keycloak-admin-client` 3.4.3 you can retrieve users with specific role as follows.

```
RoleResource roleResource = keycloak.realm("realm_name").roles().get("role_name");  
    Set<UserRepresentation> users = roleResource.getRoleUserMembers();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In that case how can I know if the user belongs to the group that I am interested in?

Comment: You use List<String> groups = userRep.getGroups();

Comment: For getting the roles of a group you can use keycloak.realm("myRealm").groups().group("groupId").roles()

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already done that. What I am looking for us an alternative way of retrieving a user from a known group without getting all the groups and then filtering as  keycloak.realm("myRealm").groups().group("groupId") 

this takes too much time when there are many groups...hence looking for an alternative

Comment: I am trying to do exactly that, but the user always 404's, and if I get the user, it's group- and role-fields are always null. I can see the role correctly in the admin console though. My requesting account is realm-admin. Any idea what it might be?